# Java Guessing Game Project (Beginner)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, methods

I'm currently working on a java project, and im supposed to make a program that generates a number between 1000 and 2000, then gives you the chance to enter the amount of players, takes in all the names and guesses in two different arrays, then create two methods, one to find the closest guess to the actual numbers and another to report or find the winner match it up with their guess and print it out. Im having trouble with my second method, im drawing a blank on the logic part right now this is my code and output:

```
public static void reportWinner (int answer, int winner, int [] array, String [] array1)
{
    ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList tempList1 = new ArrayList();
    int counter = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        temp = answer - array[index];
        temp = Math.abs(temp);
        if(temp == winner)
        {
            counter++;
            tempList.add(array1[index]);
            tempList1.add(array[index]);
        }
    }
    for(int index = 0; index < tempList.size(); index++)
    {
        if(tempList.size() == 1);
        {
            System.out.println("The winner is " + tempList.get(0) + ", with a guess of " + tempList1.get(0) + " which is " 
                             + winner + " away from the actual number of jelly beans.");
            if(tempList.size() > 1)
            {
                System.out.println("The winners are: ");
                System.out.println(tempList.get(index) + ", with a guess of " + tempList1.get(index) + " which is " 
                                   + winner + " away from the actual number of jelly beans.");
            }
        }
        if(tempList.size() == 1 && winner == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("The winner is " + tempList.get(0) + ", with a guess of " + tempList1.get(0) + " which is " 
                             + "the exact number of jelly beans in the jar.");
            if(tempList.size() > 1)
            {
                System.out.println("The winners are: ");
                System.out.println(tempList.get(index) + ", with a guess of " + tempList1.get(index) + " which is " 
                                    + "the exact number of jelly beans in the jar.");
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

This is the output it is producing when there is more than one winner.

```
There were 1532 jelly beans in the jar.
The winner is Stan, with a guess of 1200 which is 332 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
The winners are: 
Stan, with a guess of 1200 which is 332 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
The winner is Stan, with a guess of 1200 which is 332 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
The winners are: 
greg, with a guess of 1200 which is 332 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
The winner is Stan, with a guess of 1200 which is 332 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
The winners are: 
Jim, with a guess of 1200 which is 332 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
```

This is what it should look like

```
There were 1500 jelly beans in the jar.

The winners are:

Mike with a guess of 1475, which is 25 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
Tony with a guess of 1525, which is 25 away from the actual number of jelly beans.
```

Im having trouble with the method portion i know this much but if you need to see the rest of the code let me know any help would be appreciated, thanks.
(I think i need a way to void the first print out if the counter passes one but im not sure how to go about this)

Comment: Remove that semicolon from the end of this line: `if(tempList.size() == 1);`.

Comment: removed it and now there is no output whatsoever

Comment: Never,  never use raw types! Just a sidenote.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I have made a lot of changes in your code because I did not understand it. Following changes:

- No raw types
- Only one loop to find the winner
- Only one array with the player and their numbers
- A different loop for the output

Here is the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GuesNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The number we want to guess
        final int theNumber = 1500;
        // A random set of players and their numbers
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            players.add(new Player("Player " + i, (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 1000)) + 1000)));
        }
        // Call of your function (with less arguments)
        reportWinner(theNumber, players);
    }

    public static void reportWinner(int theNumber, List<Player> players) {
        // Here we store the minimal diff between THE number 
        // and the number of the potential winner
        Integer minDiff = null;
        // Here we store the winners
        ArrayList<Player> winners = new ArrayList<>();
        // Find the winners
        for (Player player : players) {
            int diff = Math.abs(player.number - theNumber);
            // We have a potential winner the player is the first 
            // we check or his number is less or equal then 
            // the minimal diff
            if (minDiff == null || minDiff <= diff) {
                // We have to clear all potential winners, 
                // if the number of the player is smaller then
                // the minimal diff
                if (minDiff != null && minDiff > diff) {
                    winners.clear();
                }
                // Add a potential winner
                winners.add(player);                    
                minDiff = diff;
            };
        }
        // Let's do the output
        System.out.println("There were " + theNumber + " jelly beans in the jar\n");
        System.out.println("The winner " + (winners.size() == 1 ? "is" : "are") + ":\n");
        for (Player player : winners) {
            System.out.print(player.name + " with a gues of " + player.number + ", wich is " + minDiff + " away from the actual number of jelly beans. ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static class Player {

        String name;
        int number;

        public Player(String name, int number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is always good to explain where/what the issue was and what you've changed.

Comment: @Tom - You are right. But I think that the method in the question has a very individual style. Therefore I have changed the whole method.

Comment: This is not wrong, but OP should what his error was and what the improvements in your program are. For example the much better way to iterate the `winners` list, the lack of raw types and so on.

Comment: @Tom - Thank you for your notes - they are right. I have explained my changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. Note: it is recommended to use meaningful variable names rather than `array` or `tempList` to make the code more readable.

```
public static void reportWinner (int answer, int winner, int [] array, String [] array1)
{
    ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList tempList1 = new ArrayList();
    int temp = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        temp = answer - array[index];
        temp = Math.abs(temp);
        if(temp == winner)
        {
            tempList.add(array1[index]);
            tempList1.add(array[index]);
        }
    }
    if(tempList.size() > 1) {
        System.out.println("The winners are: ");
    } else if(tempList.size() == 1) {
        System.out.println("The winner is: ");
    }
    for(int index = 0; index < tempList.size(); index++)
    {
        String suffix = "";
        if(winner == 0) {
            suffix = "the exact number of jelly beans in the jar."
        } else {
            suffix = winner + " away from the actual number of jelly beans."
        }
        System.out.println(tempList.get(index) + ", with a guess of " + tempList1.get(index) + " which is " + suffix);
    }
}
```